# nginx django suburl doesn't work

Tags: nginx, configuration, django, url

I'm trying to setup django under some suburl, lets say `/myproject`, with nginx and uwsgi. However, I can't get it working. Whatever I try, seems that `uwsgi_modifier1 30;` option doesn't work. I always get doubled path, instead of `localhost:8000/myproject`, I get `localhost:8000/myproject/myproject`

What am I missing? Here are the relevant files:

Django urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', lambda x: HttpResponse('Hello world'), name='home'),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I didn't change anything in default django settings.py, except adding DB info. And here is nginx conf file:

```
upstream mydjango {
    server unix:///home/username/www/myproject/c.sock;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;

    location /myproject/ {
        uwsgi_pass mydjango;
        include /home/username/www/myproject/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /myproject;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
}
```

and I'm starting uwsgi from command line for now with:

```
uwsgi --socket c.sock --module myproject.wsgi --chmod-socket=666
```

I don't find any errors in the logs, just 404, because there is no nginx conf for path `/` on `8000` port, but there is no `django` url rule to match `/myproject/myproject/` either. So where is my mistake? If that is relevant, I'm trying this on debian wheezy, nginx the latest from mainline, python-3.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `rewrite` instead of `uwsgi_modifier1` ?

```
...
    location /myproject {
        rewrite /myproject(.*) $1 break;
        include /home/username/www/myproject/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass mydjango;
    }
...
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, any ideas why uwsgi_modifier1 doesn't work?

Comment: @RapolasK. No idea, I have never used this directive.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working! Trick was to tell Django about the path with `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` as well and modify static paths. For me this solution is good enough as suburl is only configured in local settings for Django and in nginx.conf.

Ubuntu 14.04 + Django 1.8 + uwsgi 1.9.17.1 + nginx 1.4.6

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.23 firstsite.com www.firstsite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /1/static {
        root /home/ubuntu/firstsite;
    }

    location /1 {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /1;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/ubuntu/firstsite/firstsite.sock;
    }
}
```

Add three lines to Django firstsite/settings.py:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/1'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '%s/static/admin/' % FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME
STATIC_URL = '%s/static/' % FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME
```

For the completeness, here is my uwsgi firstsite.ini using virtualenv in ~home/Env:

```
[uwsgi]
project = firstsite
base = /home/ubuntu

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```